# Next JS styled components dark mode themeing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

This probably has answer, but I was unable to find it

I am using styled components with next js and use-dark-mode hook to trigger theme change/detect

global styles switch before loading

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    body {
        background: ${props => props.theme.background};
        color: ${props => props.theme.color};
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
`
```

but having simple styled component like this one

```
const BackgroundTopAppBar = styled.header`
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.appBarHeaderBackground};
`;
```

doesnt change upon page loading and remains light theme colored

also inside _document.js is implemented next-js team example of how to use styled components for SSR and it works well, **but for styled components that are not global dark mode is not activated** after page is refreshed

thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for a solution, use GlobalStyles and in there modify current color of element because GlobalStyles will apply it before loading

```
export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    body {
        background: ${props => props.theme.background};
        color: ${props => props.theme.color};
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    ${BackgroundTopAppBar} {
        background-color: ${props => props.theme.appBarHeaderBackground};
    }
`
```